# Can't find main(String[]) method in class: TapeDeck. The main method is in the other class which runs the program

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I have two classes. When the I put class TapeDeckTestDrive first on the text editor, it runs fine. When I put the TestDrive class first, it gives the error that it can't find the main class. Why is this?

```
class TapeDeck {
    boolean canRecord = false;
    void playTape(){
        System.out.println("tape playing");
    }
    void recordTape(){
        System.out.println("tape recording");
    }
}

class TapeDeckcTestDrive{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        TapeDeck t = new TapeDeck();
        t.canRecord = true;
        t.playTape();

        if (t.canRecord == true) {
            t.recordTape();
        }
    }
}
```

ERROR ON THIS FORMAT

VS

FOLLOWING WORKS FINE:

```
class TapeDeckcTestDrive{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        TapeDeck t = new TapeDeck();
        t.canRecord = true;
        t.playTape();

        if (t.canRecord == true) {
            t.recordTape();
        }
    }
}

class TapeDeck {
    boolean canRecord = false;
    void playTape(){
        System.out.println("tape playing");
    }
    void recordTape(){
        System.out.println("tape recording");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your java class (file) name?

Comment: The easy way, and the best too, to solve this is to have one class per file.

Comment: @Abdul Hussain   Please tell the file name

Comment: *it runs fine, it gives the error*: what is "it". How do you execute your application?

Comment: @Brother
 Ok so I have created two files. Both file names match the class name. However, I am getting a different error now when I run TapeDeckTestDrive class.

TapeDeckTestDrive.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
        TapeDeck t = new TapeDeck();

Comment: @JBNizet on the cmd terminal. "java TapeDeckTestDrive.java

Comment: That's not the best way to execute a class. First you compile your code with javac. Then you use java and pass the fully-qualified name of the class containing the main method.

Comment: @JBNizet ok thanks. I learned that but for whatever reason forgot to implement that.  I am getting the following error now: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: failed to access class TapeDeck from class TapeDeckTestDrive (TapeDeck is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; TapeDeckTestDrive is in unnamed module of loader com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main$MemoryClassLoader @18bf3d14)
        at TapeDeckTestDrive.main(TapeDeckTestDrive.java:3)

I will continue figuring this out on my own but help is appreciated.

Comment: @Brother That is completely incorrect. Don't post misinformation or guesswork here. Java looks for the main method inside the class you specify.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After you compile the code using the command:

```
javac fileName.java
```

Run the java `.class` file by only specifying `fileName` without the `.java` extension

```
java fileName
```

if you use `fileName.java` it won't run the specific `.class` file; it will try to interpret the `.java` file. if you want to interpret a `.java` file then parent class must contain the `main(String[])` method.

Answer (score 5):

First, You have to compile the File by using `javac`.
Then, You have to Run the file.

Classname where main is written.

```
javac filename.java
java classname
```

Answer (score 3):

You Can Run the java program in two ways.

1. Directly run the java program by

   ```
     java example_program.java
   ```

   In this type compilation and Execution happens at runtime. That is
   Byte codes is generated and executed immediately(works as a interpreter)
   So,**You must use the superclass(Containing the main method) at first followed by other
   compound classes.**

**Note:**
No .class file will generate. That means, it will generate byte code internally and will execute. Programmer's cannot view the class file.

2. In Second type, First, you should compile,

   ```
    javac example_program.java
   ```

It will generate the **example_program.class** . Then, Execute the class file using,

```
     java example_program
```

Here, the order of writing classes doesn't impact. you can write the classes in any order. it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I got your problem.

First of all, check your **classpath** that you have set in **Environment Variables**

Follow the following steps:

- ***Step 1: *** Right Click on This PC --> Advanced system settings --> Environment Variables
- ***Step 2: *** Edit the variable **classpath** and add a new path or edit your old path that you have set. The path should be: **C:\Program Files\Java_Home\jdk..\lib;.;**
  ***Note***: The "." is must after a semicolon (;).
- ***Step 3: *** Close the CMD and open it again.
- ***Step 4: *** Now compile your using javac command: `javac FileName.java`
- ***Step 5: *** Run your code using java command: `java ClassName`

And there you go...

Answer (score 0):

I split it into two files and added public to the classes/methods as well as the boolean. Now the code runs.

Comment: Please respond to comments in comments, or by editing the question. Answers should be answers.

Answer (score 0):

In some JDK's , JVM looks after the entry point function first due to which it need to be written first then the rest of the code. As main function is our entry point function it must be written first.

Answer (score 0):

```
Steps 1. 
--You have to compile the File by using javac. Then, You have to Run the file.

--Classname where main is written.

-- javac filename.java
-- java classname


It causing error due to:-
class TapeDeck {
    boolean canRecord = false;
    void playTape(){
        System.out.println("tape playing");
    }
    void recordTape(){
        System.out.println("tape recording");
    }
}

class TapeDeckcTestDrive{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        TapeDeck t = new TapeDeck();
        t.canRecord = true;
        t.playTape();

        if (t.canRecord == true) {
            t.recordTape();
        }
    }
}

--Your tapedeck class doesn't main (String[]).
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put "public static void main" class first and then other methods in your code. It will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem.  Then I realised I wrote the wrong spelling instead of main I wrote mian.

So just check with spelling mistakes.

**Before**

```
public static void mian(String args[]){
      int a[][] ={{3,3},{5,-1},{-2,4}};
      int k=2;
    
      nearestCar(a,k);
}
```

**After**

```
public static void main(String args[]){
      int a[][] ={{3,3},{5,-1},{-2,4}};
      int k=2;

      nearestCar(a,k);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

open your myClass.java directory

open cmd there

execute

```
javac myClass.java
```

then

```
java myClass
```

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same problem. I used to run the file directly before compiling. Since you have two class files, it reads the first class and checks for `main` method. If it's present then it will run or else it will thrown an error

> Can't find main(String[]) method in class

To avoid this sort of error, always compile the java file usng (`javac fileName.java`) and then run the (`java fileName`).

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't see what your answer adds to the other [ten] answers. Can you tell me?